# FileSaver.js and Blob.js - Change directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, blob

I am using using fileSaver.js and Blob.js to save a file like this:

```
var blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Is there a trick I can use to specify my own directory?

Comment: that's a browser setting. you can set a certain folder for all downloads, but JS cannot specify one or another, just whatever the browser provides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't.

> [..] that is not possible due to security restrictions in the File API. The user will have to choose the directory a file is saved to.

https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/42

Comment: I was going to post the same...this is the right answer... +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are here because you want **the user** to have the ability to change file's name or target directory before saving, he has to change his browser settings in order to do it.

For Google Chrome:

1. Click 3 dots ('Customise and control Google Chrome) in the right top
   corner of the browser window
2. Click ‘Settings’
3. Click ‘Advanced’ (bottom of the screen)
4. Scroll to ‘Downloads’.
5. Check ‘**Ask where to save each file before downloading**’ option.