# is there a way to use file-saver ( with Angular ) to let user specify download location?

Tags: angular

here the report.xlsx is downloaded to the browser default download location.
I want the user to specify where to download the file.

```
 onSelect(data: any) {
    this.reportService
      .generateAllEmployeesReport(data.value)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (data.value === 'xls') FileSaver.saveAs(response, 'report.xlsx');
      });
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileSaver.js and Blob.js - Change directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573508/filesaver-js-and-blob-js-change-directory)